# Sub-request response stops the initial request in Kohana 3.2?

Tags: curl, request, kohana, kohana-3.2

Following: https://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/requests

I have this code:

```
$request = Request::factory($url);

$request
    ->client()
    ->options(array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'test' . ':' . 'token'
    ));

$response = $request->execute();

$response = json_decode($response);

if(is_array($response) && isset($response['product_feed_url']))
{
    echo "Ok Access";
}else{
    echo "No Access";
}
```

Inside a my controller function action_getsettings().

I am using the Request::factory() instead of manual curl and it all works fine, but the problem is that the response of the $request does not get stoerd in the $response - it just outputs directly and exits the controller (it doesnt go to the json_decode and if statement)

Also tried `$response = $request->execute()->body();` but it still just outputs as if i did `return $response;`

Why does this happen?

Comment: Where are you placing this code? Inside a controller, this triggers an error for me. ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method Request_Client_Internal::options()

Answer (score 0):

1. Where are you placing this code? Inside an controller, this triggers an error for me.:
   ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method Request_Client_Internal::options().
2. Are you making a call to an internal uri or an external? Internal works perfectly fine for me.

`

```
$uri = 'controller/action';
$request = Request::factory($uri);
$request->execute();
```

Comment: I am making a external request. API request. Inside a controller yes, no errors for options() that works fine